# html/jquery combine input type: text within radio

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input

I'm making a form and would like text input field to be inside of a radio/checkbox input field. What is the right way to do it?

```
    <form>
     Question 1:
     <label for="Q01_A01"><input name="Q01" id="Q01_A01" type="radio" value="Q01_A01" />Yes </label>
     <label for="Q01_A02"><input name="Q01" id="Q01_A02" type="radio" value="Q01_A02" />No, why? ...TEXT FIELD HERE.....</label>
     <label for="Q01_A03"><input name="Q01" id="Q01_A03" type="radio" value="Q01_A03" />I don't know </label>
    </form>
```

I'm not sure if this is necessary but I think it would look good if someone selects 'No' option, the text field appears - otherwise it's hidden. If there's an easy way to do it with jQuery, I'd be happy to use it.

Comment: First of all there should never be more then one element with the same `id`. Also more correctly to put separate `label` tags for each text note for the radio, e.g.: `<label><input name="Q01" id="Q01" type="radio" value="Q1_A01" />Yes</label>`, so radio will change it's state also if you will click on it's label. Now, what is the problem to listen on change event and show additional text field when needed?

Comment: You're absolutely right, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you could do it in a more general sense: http://jsfiddle.net/mYZaQ/62/
There are a few things that have to be consistent about the form though:

- The inputs must be within a `label`
- The text input must have the name `why`
- The radiobutton with an extra input field must have the class `more`
- The text input field has to be directly behind or below the
  radiobutton named `why`

HTML:

```
<form>
<label for="Q01">
    Question 1:<br/>
 <input name="Q01" id="Q1_A01" type="radio" value="Q1_A01" />Yes <br />
 <input name="Q01" id="Q1_A02" type="radio" value="Q1_A02" class="more" />No, why?
    <input name="why" id="Q1_A03" type="text" value="" /><br />
 <input name="Q01" id="Q1_A04" type="radio" value="Q1_A04" />I don't know <br />
</label>
<br />
<label for="Q02">
    Question 2:<br/>
 <input name="Q02" id="Q2_A01" type="checkbox" value="Q2_A01" />Yes <br />
 <input name="Q02" id="Q2_A02" type="checkbox" value="Q2_A02" class="more" />No, why?
    <input name="why" id="Q2_A03" type="text" value="" /><br />
 <input name="Q02" id="Q2_A04" type="checkbox" value="Q2_A04" />I don't know <br />
</label>
</form>
```

...and the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name$='why']").hide();

  $("label input[type='radio']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('more')) $(this).next().show();
    else $(this).parent().children("input[type='text']").hide();
  });

  $("label input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('more')) $(this).next().toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: This looks good! What if there were more of these in the form, do I have to rewrite it every time for each question?

Comment: That depends a bit on how you want the check boxes to work, but try the above. I updated the jsfiddle as well.
I think it's better to ask a new question instead of extending this answer any more than this. Each question should be kept as specific as possible.

Answer (score 1):

yes this is very simple.. 
you can achieve this by following code 
First of all you cannot have same id's for all input radio's id should be different.

```
<form>
    <label for="Q01">
     Question 1:
     <input name="Q01" id="Q01" type="radio" value="Q1_A01" />Yes <br />
     <input name="Q01" id="Q02" type="radio" value="Q1_A02" />No, why?<input type="text" name="reason" id="reason" class="noreason" /><br />
     <input name="Q01" id="Q02" type="radio" value="Q1_A03" />I don't know <br />
    </label>
    </form>
```

SCRIPT jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $(".noreason").css("display", "none");
 $("#Q02").click (function() {

  if ($(this).checked == true )
  {
       $(".noreason").css("display", "block");
  }
 })

});
```

Comment: Corresponding to the issue with `label`, it is better to use `change` event neither `click`.

Comment: onchange event has some problem with IE browsers thats the only reason i prefer onclick. anyways thats not the question..

Answer (score 1):

Hi what you are trying to achieve is easy by binding the click or change event to the visibility of the text input you don't really need jquery for this. If you are using  jquery you can do $("#radioId").change(function(){$("textinputId").show()}; if you have the text input as display:none on doc ready. Hope this ain't too bad, from  phone..